# Is there a shortcut for color chooser in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, colors

Is there a shortcut for color chooser in NetBeans?

I found this same query on NetBeans website, it was said that this was possible but I can't find an actual answer how to do it.

I mean this: when I am in a CSS file and I am editing a property that involves a color, the color chooser pops up automatically. I would like to have the color chooser pop up on demand when I am editing any file (e.g. a PHP file). It would be very helpful.

I already looked in Options -> Keymap and there seems to be no shortcut containing the word "color".

Thanks.

Comment: same problem here! you got the answer?

Comment: Sadly, no. There doesn't seem to be a solution, what a shame with such a great software as NetBeans.

Answer (score 5):

In the editor, click the text representing the color (you don't even have to highlight the whole thing), then hit Ctrl+Spacebar.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not ideal in Netbeans 8.0.2 you can do the following:

1. open any CSS file that contains a rule with a property that takes colour as value and place the cursor inside the declaration block of that rule,
2. in the top menu click on `Window -> Web -> CSS Styles`,
3. click on the dropdown with colour values and scroll right to the top,
4. click on **Choose Color** and a colour chooser will appear.

You can now close the CSS file (if you like) and open any type of file - the CSS Styles window will stay and you can repeat the above procedure starting from step 3.

[image: colour chooser in Netbeans 8.0.2]

P.S. Netbeans has a [bug tracker](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) that is not just for reporting bugs:

> Issues = Bugs, **Feature Requests**, and **Enhancements**